# Pac4j Using Jwt Encription for OidcClient using P12 Certificate as client assertions

Tags: jwt, pac4j

I have a use case where I need to set the JWT encryption in my Client application.I have referenced this doc but not sure where I should link it to even in configurations I am finding it difficult.
Referred Project:https://github.com/pac4j/jee-pac4j-demo/tree/5.0.x

UseCase:I have a P12 certificate(I can  Convert into other format as supprted by pac4j
) and i Want to Use them in OIDC configuration for my ISVA client.the P12 certificate  has a password.I want to use it as a key for client assertioncan you please help me out on this.

I want to set configuration for JWT assertion for PAc4j using a key mentioned

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "client assertion"? Can you elaborate where you want to set the certificate in the `OidcConfiguration`?

Comment: Hi,
So the P12 can be modified to a RSA Private Key which is set by the IDP , What functionality i am looking for is JWT Assertion using a private key by the client , so i will be giving my oidcClient with a private key.
I have a reference code for later version of java 8.
https://www.pac4j.org/docs/clients/openid-connect.html

Comment: Indeed, the use of a private key for JWT assertion is not available for Java 8, but only for Java 11 and 17 as you can see in the docs.